# Questions about cocoapods installation

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

```
Terminal: CocoaPods installed but not working.
You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with
is different from the one being used to invoke it.
This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.
```

My ruby ​​version is 3.2.2 and my `activesupport` version is 7.1.1, so why can't my CocoaPods operate? My computer is mac(14.0)

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Uninstall cocoapods completely and re-install. The error only told you so. This error is usually caused by a major upgrade of macOS.

Comment: How to cope with this question? Can you give a solution?

Comment: To re-install see
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.